# Do I need to change the way my URL slugs are being created?

Tags: php, url, smarty, slug, openstack-swift

I'm an apprentice digital marketer so I have very little knowledge of coding.

The agency that designed & developed my companies website has dropped off the face of the planet and cannot assist us.

The website uses (from what I can see) PHP, smarty and swift framework - http://www.candojobs.co.uk

Currently the URLs for a job post are displayed like this:

http://www.candojobs.co.uk/jobs/267/rq92159/project-manager-level-4

Is this harming our SEO? Could the URLs be in a better format?

If so, how can we change them? I have searched through all of the website .tpl and .php files and didn't find anything. I had a quick look at the htaccess file and I saw this:

```
# Recruiters
    RewriteRule ^recruiters/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-@%]+)?$ doindex.php?page=recruiters&id=$1&companyName=$2 [QSA,L]

# News
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-@%]+)?$ doindex.php?page=news&id=$1 [QSA,L]

# Jobs
RewriteRule ^jobs/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ doindex.php?page=jobs&id=$1 [QSA,L]**
```

Could this have something to do with the way the URLs are handled?

If anyone has any idea about this as I confused myself just writing this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that the `rq92159/project-manager-level-4` portion of the URL isn't being used in the URL rewrite at all, as it is only matching the `267` to pass to the `doindex.php` with the `$1`.  The other seems absolutely useless.  Though, removing it would require a rewrite of the `.htaccess` as well as how links are created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm guessing I should probably hire a freelancer to try and sort this for us?

Comment: Most likely.  The `project-manager-level-4` will help with SEO and ranking, however, the `rq...` is pointless.  You can view the same page as your link with http://www.candojobs.co.uk/doindex.php?page=jobs&id=267 However, just the ID would be bad for SEO since the 'link' would have the page title in it.

Comment: Honestly, in my opinion, SEO is 90% BS (content is king) - those URLs won't really affect your search engine placement in any great way; *rq92159/project-manager-level-4* is just a fake suffix to make the URL more search engine friendly (the *project-manager-level-4* bit makes sense but the *rq92159* part looks like your previous developers were trying to make the URLs look more techie so they could fleece you for more cash - it does nothing) - if Search Engines had genuine problems with *slighty odd* looking URLs Amazon wouldn't appear on any search engine ... ever.

Comment: Not a problem OP. @CD001 Content is king, but when the url has the page title (That is the same/close to the properly formatted content title), it does move up in the rankings a bit.  As for the `rq...` yeah, it's absolute crap.  Side note, it's odd that for the `recruiters/`... that the `id` comes before the `company`. Good luck on getting it sorted out OP. ^^

Comment: @Jon agreed - that's why I said the *project-manager-level-4* bit in the URL makes sense ... it doesn't make a **huge** difference but it is a difference nonetheless ;)